# Regex: How to split by string, sybloms and spaces correctly ? "one!@# two!!?"

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have the following program that uses a regular expression:

```
const regex = /(\W{1,})|[\w][\w'`’‘-]*[\w-]|'|\w+/gm;
```

When running:

```
console.log("one!@# two!!?".match(regex) || []);
```

I get:

```
["one", "!@# ", "two", "!!?"]
```

I need to update the regular expression in a way that I can get at the end:

```
["one", "!@#", " ", "two", "!!?"]
```

Comment: Exclude `\s` from `\W` and add a `\s+` alternative: ``([^\w\s]+)|\w[\w'`’‘-]*[\w-]|'|\w+|\s+``, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KsNFtx/1). Btw, `'` is not necessary here, you can remove `'|` as `[^\w\s]` matches single quotes, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match on word characters `\w+`, or non word characters except for whitspace chars `[^\w\s]+`, or whitespace chars `\s+`

You can omit the `/m` flag as there are no anchors in the pattern.

```
\w+|[^\w\s]+|\s+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A9fJR4/1)

```js
console.log("one!@# two!!?".match(/\w+|[^\w\s]+|\s+/g));
```

---

You could keep this part in the alternatives `` \w[\w'`’‘-]*[\w-] `` but that will match at least 2 characters, for example a string like `a'-`

```
[^\w\s]+|\w[\w'`’‘-]*[\w-]|\w+|\s+
```

You can see the matches at this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IyYoaa/1).